# Scheme-like lambda expressions?

Tags: elisp, scheme

Scheme syntax seems very lambda-expression-friendly. I can do this

```
(define blah
   (lambda (n) (* n n)))
```

But this isn't possible in elisp. I can do this

```
(defun simple (x)
  ((lambda (n) (* n n)) x))
```

but of course not this

```
(defun simple
   (lambda (n) (* n n)))
```

or this

```
defun simple ()
       (lambda (n) (* n n)))
```

Hence, elisp seems a step removed from the Scheme world of "purer" lambda expressions . . . or am I, the beginner, missing something here . . . or is this not a big deal, i.e., there's nothing gained with the Scheme way of doing lambda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a big deal. You can still:

```cl
(setq blah-1
      (lambda (n) (* n n)))
(funcall blah-1 3)
;; => 9
(fset 'blah-2 (lambda (n) (* n n)))
(blah-2 3)
;; => 9
```

Basically, Elisp is LISP-2, and Scheme is LISP-1.